# KEY_UP event of ctrl key blocks KEY_UP event of 'c' key

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I have noticed that many times, there is no `KEY_UP` event for <kbd>C</kbd> key. I believe it happens in cases `KEY_UP` event for <kbd>C</kbd> key should be thrown just before or after `KEY_UP` event for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>key.

Why does this happen?  How can I catch the `KEY_UP` for <kbd>C</kbd> key?

Comment: Can you provide some code to demonstrate the problem?  It seems extremely odd that there would be no keyup event for the 'c' key.

Comment: I cant prove any code.
By the way, KEY_DOWN for 'c' key is never dispatched while ctrl key is down.

Comment: The code in general is complex (there is no point to provide only the addEventListener command and the definition of the function - they are obvious).  In addition, the code belongs to the company i work in - i can't copy the code.

Comment: @Erik Sapir. You don't need to copy the actual code, just the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Erik I'd repeat what @Juan said.  If you want help, I'm going to need a runnable sample I can test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function myButton_keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            myButton.label="";
            if(event.ctrlKey)
                myButton.label+="Ctrl-";
            if(event.altKey)
                myButton.label+="Alt-";
            myButton.label+=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>



<s:Button id="myButton" keyUp="myButton_keyUpHandler(event)" />


</s:Application>
```