# ctrl button sometimes block KEY_UP event for 'c' key

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Try the following code:

```
myListener = new Object();
myListener.onKeyUp = function() {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.CONTROL) && Key.getCode() == 67) {
        //Ctrl+C
        trace("Ctrl+C key down!");
    }
};
Key.addListener(myListener);
```

hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and start pressing <kbd>C</kbd>. From some point you will notice that there is no KEY_UP event for the <kbd>C</kbd> key (there will also be no event for <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd> and maybe more).
For most of the button the KEY_UP event will still be dispatched.

Why is that? Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you turn this into a full runnable sample? Why does this sound eerily familiar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KEY_UP event of ctrl key blocks KEY_UP event of 'c' key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568907/key-up-event-of-ctrl-key-blocks-key-up-event-of-c-key)

Comment: You can use this code as a full runnable example.
you will notice that from some point, no messages are thrown to trace.

Comment: I have change the code to a more easy-to-trace code

Comment: The code isn't a full runnable sample.  I can't copy and paste it in into application as is.

Comment: Just create a new fla with this code, publish and test.

Comment: Have you tried checking the "Disable Keyboard Shortcuts" option under the Control menu in the debug player?

Comment: The problem happens not only in debug player. It also happens with some of the browsers (such as IE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

[KEY_UP event of ctrl key blocks KEY_UP event of 'c' key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568907/key-up-event-of-ctrl-key-blocks-key-up-event-of-c-key/3569608#3569608)

Also take sure your flash object is focused on browser page, and browser don't catching your keyboard events.

Comment: are you compiling for FP10 and in Flex 4?